# Interpreting Scikit-Learn model output, extra trees classifier differing measures

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a set of data on which I'm developing a predictive model using Extra Trees Classifier, As the following code shows, on the initial set of code showed et_scores looked quite disappointing the I ran fit see further below and it looks better, then I did a learning graph and things don't look too hot. All in all quite confusing.
Initial code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
#split the dataset for train and test
combnum['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(combnum)) <= .75
train, test = combnum[combnum['is_train']==True], combnum[combnum['is_train']==False]

et = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=10, random_state=0)

labels = train[list(label_columns)].values
tlabels = test[list(label_columns)].values

features = train[list(columns)].values
tfeatures = test[list(columns)].values

et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels.ravel(), n_jobs=-1)
print("{0} -> ET: {1})".format(label_columns, et_score))
```

Gives me:

```
['Campaign_Response'] -> ET: [ 0.58746427  0.31725003  0.43522521])
```

Not so hot!
then on my held out data:

```
 et.fit(features,labels.ravel())
 et.score(tfeatures,tlabels.ravel())
 Out[16]:0.7434136771300448
```

Not so bad
then on the training data:

```
et.score(features,labels.ravel())
Out[17]:0.85246473144769563
```

Again, pretty good but no relation to the earlier score?
Then running:

```
from sklearn.learning_curve import validation_curve


def plot_validation_curve(estimator, X, y, param_name, param_range,
                      ylim=(0, 1.1), cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring=None):
    estimator_name = type(estimator).__name__
    plt.title("Validation curves for %s on %s"
          % (param_name, estimator_name))
    plt.ylim(*ylim); plt.grid()
    plt.xlim(min(param_range), max(param_range))
    plt.xlabel(param_name)
    plt.ylabel("Score")

    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
        estimator, X, y, param_name, param_range,
        cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, scoring=scoring)

    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.semilogx(param_range, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.semilogx(param_range, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    print("Best test score: {:.4f}".format(test_scores_mean[-1]))
```

followed by:

```
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(max_depth=8)
param_name = 'max_depth'
param_range = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]

plot_validation_curve(clf, features,labels.ravel(),
                  param_name, param_range, scoring='roc_auc')
```

give me a graph and legend that does not seem to reflect the prior information:

```
Best test score: 0.3592
```

[image: Learning curve]

and finally the sklearn metrics gives me

```
Accuracy:0.737 

Classification report
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.76      0.79      0.78      8311
          1       0.70      0.66      0.68      6134

avg / total       0.74      0.74      0.74     14445
```

seems to me that I should be better able to interpret this stuff can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you experience here is that different cross-validation methods and classifier parameters lead to different scores.

In your first experiment, you are comparing results from the [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) method with your own 75%/25% random split. The cross_val_score method uses the [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html) method with a K of 3 to determine the folds. StratifiedKFold more or less preserves the order of the data, while your random split removes any natural order in the data through random sampling. That may explain the difference in the scores, especially when your data has some dependency on the natural order. For example if your data is ordered by timestamp, the characteristics of the data might have changed over time. That leads to inferior scores when train and test sets come from different time periods, which would be the case for the StratifiedKFold sampling.

In the second experiment you are using default parameters for the classifier and a cross-validation with 5 folds, which again leads to different results. For example, by default the ExtraTreeClassifier uses 10 estimators, but in your first experiment you used 200 estimators - and you vary the max_depth parameter. For interpretation, the max_depth parameter determines the complexity of the trees, and with only 10 trees trained, a high number of leafs leads to overfitting, which is exactly the effect you see in the validation chart. The best test score is actually 0.6 and not 0.315, you should take the maximum score instead of the last score.

I hope this helps with the interpretation of the score and understanding of the differences. As next steps I would check the ordering of the data, and if it is temporal I would investigate it through visualization. If you expect such drift also in the data that you want to predict on in the end, you should not use random sampling - if you are confident that your training set reflects all the variation, you can shuffle the data before the tests or set the shuffle parameter of the StratifiedKFold to true. For the classifier, I would rather start with a plain RandomForestClassifier and set the n_estimators to 100, before looking at ExtraTrees.